# autocites shows no squared brackets, while autocite does

Tags: biblatex, citing, multiple-citations

For my bibliography, I have a group of references, where I have to cite the page number for one of them using `\autocites`, but the output gives no squared brackets for the citation. For `\cites`, its working properly and there is also more space between the different references.

**MWE:**

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{main.bib}
    @book{tolkien_79,
        title={The silmarillion},
        author={Tolkien, John Ronald Reuel},
        year={1979},
        publisher={Random House LLC}
    }
    
    @book{simek_05,
        title={Mittelerde: Tolkien und die germanische Mythologie},
        author={Simek, Rudolf},
        year={2005},
        publisher={CH Beck}
    }
    
    @book{mikos_07,
        title={Die" Herr der Ringe"-Trilogie: Attraktion und Faszination eines popul{\"a}rkulturellen Ph{\"a}nomens},
        author={Mikos, Lothar and Eichner, Susanne and Prommer, Elizabeth and Wedel, Michael and others},
        year={2007},
        publisher={UVK-Verlag-Ges.}
    }
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{
    range-phrase = {\,--\,}
}
    
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage[
    natbib=true,
    backend=biber,
    style=chem-angew,
    sorting=none,
    sortcites=true,
    autocite=superscript,
    maxnames=99,
    ]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{main.bib}

\begin{document}
    \lipsum[2][2] \autocite{tolkien_79, simek_05, mikos_07} \newline
    \lipsum[2][2] \cite{tolkien_79, simek_05, mikos_07} \newline    
    \lipsum[2][2]  \autocites{tolkien_79}[\ppno\,\numrange{10}{20}]{mikos_07}[\ppno\,\numrange{20}{30}]{simek_05} \newline
    \lipsum[2][2] \cites{tolkien_79}[\ppno\,\numrange{10}{20}]{mikos_07}[\ppno\,\numrange{20}{30}]{simek_05}
    
    \medskip
    
    \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

results in the following output:

[image: output]

Do I have to modify the `\DeclareCiteCommand` in the .cbx file for this purpose or is there another way to change also the `\autocites` output to square brackets?

**Bonus**

Is it possible to add a small space (like `\,`) between each reference in `\autocite` (`\supercite`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be argued that `chem-angew.cbx` is missing a `\DeclareMultiCiteCommand` to bring `\supercite` in line with `\supercites`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage[
    natbib=true,
    backend=biber,
    style=chem-angew,
    sorting=none,
    sortcites=true,
    autocite=superscript,
    maxnames=99,
]{biblatex}

\DeclareMultiCiteCommand{\supercites}[\mkbibsuperbracket]{\supercite}{\supercitedelim}

\DefineBibliographyExtras{english}{%
  \protected\def\bibrangedash{%
    \addnbthinspace\textendash\addthinspace}}

\renewcommand*{\supercitedelim}{\addcomma\addthinspace}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
Lorem\autocite{sigfridsson,worman,geer}

ipsum\cite{sigfridsson,worman,geer}    

dolor\autocites{sigfridsson}[10-20]{worman}[20-30]{geer}

sit\cites{sigfridsson}[10-20]{worman}[20-30]{geer}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Lorem [1–3] ipsum[1–3] dolor [1,2,3] sit[1, 2, pp. 10–20, 3, pp. 20–30]]